# Can't change text of a TextView in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a view, inflated from custom layout, which contains a `TextView`. 
I tried to set `TextView` text both from xml via string resource and programmatically after layout inflating - I'm still getting only `android.widget.RelativeLayout@4166f2d8` instead of normal text. What am I doing wrong?

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layers_list_item_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/layers_list_item_switch"
        blablabla... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layers_list_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layers_list_item_switch"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="@string/layers_list_default_text"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

View inflating method:

```
public View createLayerListItem (String text) {
    View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layers_list_item, null);
    TextView text_view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.layers_list_item_text);
    text_view.setText(text);
    return v;
}
```

And this views are used to fill some `ListView`:

```
ListView layers_list = (ListView)layers_dialog.findViewById(R.id.layers_list);
ArrayAdapter<View> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<View>(this, R.layout.layers_list_item, R.id.layers_list_item_text);

adapter.add(createLayerListItem("Test 1"));
adapter.add(createLayerListItem(""));
adapter.add(createLayerListItem("Very very very very very very long line"));
```

All my `TextViews` are wrong, showing `android.widget.RelativeLayout@4166f2d8`. I also tried to use default text from xml, not changing it from code at all - still I didn't got my text from resource, only address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array adapter convert your views to string array because of this, it set textview text as its class name.  So you should use like below,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.layer_list_item, R.id.layers_list_item_text);

adapter.add(createLayerListItem("Test 1"));
adapter.add(createLayerListItem("Test 2"));
adapter.add(createLayerListItem("Test 3"));


public String createLayerListItem(String text) {
        View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layer_list_item, null);
        TextView text_view = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.layers_list_item_text);
        text_view.setText(text);
        return text_view.getText().toString();
    }
```

Comment: -deleted-
Oh, I think I understand now, will try it tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I'm still getting some garbage info. 
Problem is, ArrayAdapter sets .toString() return value of given object as ListView item text.